# Path problems HTML

Tags: php, html, xcode, web

Im creating my own website, but I am having some path problems.

My scripts will not load when I refer to the path.
I have simply created a folder called "js" under my repository and are trying the following code:

```
<script src="js/startup.js"></script>
```

But the script wont load.

I've also programmed some PHP scripts and used include, and it seems to work fine there.
Any tips?

Regards

Comment: Are you calling that from file that is in the root folder ? Try absolute path

Comment: Can you please post the code and directory structure of your project in order to get an idea of what is happening?

Comment: just a guess - if you're calling the script before the DOM has been loaded it won't work

Answer (score 2):

When including resources for the browser, the path is relative to the web root but when including php files, it is relative to the current file.

```
/project
  /webRoot
    -index.php
    /js
      -startup.js
  /lib
    -some.php
```

given this structure, your script tag would work, even if included in `some.php`. In index.php, you would need

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/some.php');
```